# Where would I place the program if I wanted a 0 to end it?

Tags: java, loops

If I wanted to end the program if a person enters "0" before any other numbers are entered would I use (and where would I place them?)

```
while (number == 0){
System.out.println("No numbers are entered except 0");
System.exit(0);}"
```

or would I use

```
if (number == 0){
System.out.println("No numbers are entered except 0");
System.exit(0);}"
```

My program is the following:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Count2{
public static void main(String[] args){

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int number, maxNum=0, count=0;

System.out.print("Enter a number (0 ends the input): ");
  do {
   number = input.nextInt();
   if (number > maxNum){
   count = 0;
   maxNum = number;
   }
   if (number == maxNum){
    count++;
   }

 }
while (number !=0);

System.out.println("The maximum numver is " +maxNum);
System.out.println("The count for the max number is " + count);
}

}}
```

I have tried adding the code to enter the integer before the "do" along with the exit code but when I do that, my count is messed up at the end

Comment: The program you have seems OK to me, without adding anything.  Why do you want to change it?

Comment: @markspace I want to change it so that if a user enters 0 first thing before they enter a number that's not 0, it will output "No numbers are entered except 0"

Comment: I think you must check if `number` is 0 or not before two if statements

Comment: @TaQuangTu If I put `if (number == 0){
System.out.println("No numbers are entered except 0");
System.exit(0);}` before the first if statement, the code exits completely after any 0. I want it so that I can still input some numbers, then 0, then have it find the max and count as well

Comment: @Tanmayjain Not at all, I want it to still keep going line by line

Comment: Basically I want it to look like this in the end: [link](https://imgur.com/a/TJhyckO)

Comment: @Derk320 ok got it.

Comment: @Derk320 Please review the answers below and upvote and/or accept

Answer (score 2):

I would just go for a `while` true loop. Note that `count` should be set to `1` in the first instance

```
int number=0, maxNum=0, count=0;
while (true) {

   number = input.nextInt();
   if (number == 0) {
     break;
   }

   if (number > maxNum){
      count = 1;   // if greater than existing then set to one
      maxNum = number;
   }
   else if (number == maxNum){
      count++;
   }
}

// print
if (count == 0){   // if a non-zero was entered then `count` will be `1`
    System.out.println("No numbers are entered except 0");
}
```

Comment: if you are setting count = 1 then move this `if (number == maxNum){
      count++;
   }` above it as it will increase the count 2 times

Comment: I also made this mistake while suggesting this to OP

Comment: @Tanmayjain Yes, since the start I have been mis-reading this as `else if` hence my erroneous comment below your answer

Comment: Being `else-if` means that it will not get double incremented upon finding a new max number

Comment: [Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52808164/where-to-place-if-statements-when-looping-with-return-methods), possible HV

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *HV*? *Hypervelocity star*?